# Access violation while reading an array

Tags: c, access-violation

I am trying to print an array of structs and receiving an access violation. Not sure how to fix this. i, j, k are 0 in at the break. Any help is appreciated.

Update:Rephrasing the question, What is the correct way to access the data inside the struct? Also qwr's answer looks promising, I will have time to test later, thanks.

[image: my struct]
[image: printing array of structs]

Comment: Where is your structure allocated?

Comment: You haven't shown where your pointers have been allocated. I would suspect you missed something.

Comment: why screenshot instead of plan-old-text? :-)

Comment: You're de-referencing a null pointer soeither when you malloc'd space you didnt check for a null pointer or VS auto assigns everything to null.

Comment: Whoa, isn't it 100x easier to cut'n'paste *text* than screenshots??

Comment: @TinMan check answer.hope it be helpful

Comment: the structure is allocated and filled with data, I am just trying to figure out how to access the data in a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### About access violation:

> **Access Violation** is generally an attempt to access memory  that the CPU cannot physically address.

### Common causes:

> Dereferencing NULL pointers . (**THIS IS YOUR CASE see picture**). You want to access to 0x000(NULL) location
>
> Attempting to access memory the program does not have rights to (such
>   as kernel structures in process context)
>
> Attempting to access a
>   nonexistent memory address (outside process's address space)
>
> Attempting to write read-only memory (such as code segment)

**More :[more here in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)**

### How you should allocate (using your structure):

First You should allocate memory;*And dont forget you should write its free function,too*

Simple allocation would be such:

```
   //instead I advice PCurrentData notation 
   CurrentData AllCurrentData=malloc(NumProduct* sizeof *CurrentData);
   //memset so we can then check it with null
   memset(AllCurrentData,0,NumProduct* sizeof *CurrentData);
   int i,y;
   for(i=0;i<NumProduct;i++){
      //Noncontiguous allocation.Suits to string allocation,cause string lens differs
      AllCurrentData[i].data=malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(char**));
      memset(AllCurrentData[i].data,0,COLUMNS*sizeof(char**));
      for(j=0;j<COLUMNS;j++){
         //this is just example
         //probably you want to allocate null terminating string
          int size=strlen(your_null_terminating_string)+1;//+1 for adding null,too
          AllCurrentData[i].data[j]=malloc(size*sizeof(char));
          memcpy(AllCurrentData[i].data[j],your_null_terminating_string,size);

       }

    }
```

### Additionaly, What else is wrong in your code and proper way

Plus you are doing wrong. Looking at your structure you hold `char**`.But you try to access it with `2D [][]` array. **Why we can not? Cause there is no guarantee that** `char**` **reference to continguous allocation, or only it done ,by manually, the way that compiler can access to it with [][]**.
Plus for `char**` mostly allocation done with noncontinguous way.cause strings len differs

So Note these:

`char**` **is not equal to** 2D array `char v[][] array`. So doing `AllCurrentData[i].data[j][k]` is **wrong** to address `char**`.

only `char*` can be equally treated as one dimensional `char v[]` array. `char[]` decay to `char*`

So accessing should be done this way:

```
#define NULL 0
if(AllCurrentData[i]!=NULL && AllCurrentData[i].data[j]!=NULL){
     char* str=AllCurrentData[i].data[j];
     if(str!=NULL)
        while (str[k]!='\0'){
          printf("%c ",str[k]);++k;
         }
     }
      /*or
       while (*str){
           printf("%c ",*str);++str;
       } */
     /*but actualy you can print null terminating string directly
      (assuming you wanted this)
        if(str!=NULL)
                 printf("%s",str); 
       */
```

[more to learn about arrays and pointers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html)

Comment: +1 `char**` does *not* decay from a 2D array. It is a pointer to a pointer; period. A 2D-array `char var[N][M]` decays (and I *hate* that word) to a `char (*)[M]`